# Best email marketing software (alternative to PHPlist)

Tags: email, newsletter, mailman, phplist

Are there good alternatives to PHPlist out there?  Particularly in ruby on rails?

We are looking to build a product like www.campaignmonitor.com

thanks!

Comment: How is this a programming question? Are you looking for a library?

Answer (score 1):

Try MadMimi: https://www.madmimi.com/

Also on GitHub: https://github.com/madmimi/madmimi-gem

Answer (score 1):

I have also created a newsletter mailing software http://codecanyon.net/item/newsletter-mailer-v13/149365